# Capybara and jQuery datepicker: Capybara thinks certain dates on the calendar are clickable (valid dates) when they aren't

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec2, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a test I am doing where I am testing the available dates that my website shows for the datepicker. The datepicker is supposed to make the next X business days available, and ignore weekends and holidays.

I was testing two scenarios, 1 that looks at pickup dates for people who place orders (on July 1st) and choose to pick up, where the next 5 business days(July 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 8th, and 9th) are available. I brute force tested it with the following rspec/capybara code and it passes no problem:

```
find("#datepicker_").click

find(".ui-datepicker-group-first").should_not have_link("1")
find(".ui-datepicker-group-first").should have_link("2") 
find(".ui-datepicker-group-first").should have_link("3")
find(".ui-datepicker-group-first").should_not have_link("4")
find(".ui-datepicker-group-first").should have_link("5")
find(".ui-datepicker-group-first").should_not have_link("6")
find(".ui-datepicker-group-first").should_not have_link("7")
find(".ui-datepicker-group-first").should have_link("8")
find(".ui-datepicker-group-first").should have_link("9")
find(".ui-datepicker-group-first").should_not have_link("10")
```

The next test deals with shipping the item instead of picking up, so with a 5 day shipping time, the available dates should be the 3rd, 5th, 8th, 9th, 10th, 11th, 12th, 15th, and 16th. However, my test (same as above, but looking at range between 2nd-17th) is failing, even though the datepicker shows only the correct dates that I am expecting as available. For some reason, it's saying that the 2nd and 6th have links (i.e. selectable dates) when they clearly do not. An example of the error cna be seen below:

```
Failures:

  1) cart functionality should make the right delivery dates available in the cart
     Failure/Error: find(".ui-datepicker-group-first").should_not have_link("2")
       expected #has_link?("2") to return false, got true
     # ./cart_functionality_spec.rb:100:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>
```

I took a screenshot of what the browser looked like during the test when I froze the test with Pry right before it did the check with rpsec. The screenshot can be seen below

[image: Screenshot of datepicker available dates]

What's weird is that the July 4th, other weekends such as July 7th, and July 17th don't trigger this error. If I comment out the test for the 2nd and the 6th, the test passes. Does anyone know why this is happening?

I'm working with:
Capybara 2.1,
Rspec-rails 2.14.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Since the 2nd wasnt a link and the 12th was a link, when i used the code

```
find(".ui-datepicker-group-first").should_not have_link("2")
```

It detected a link for the date "12". This same scenario happened for the 6th and 16th. I changed the test to:

```
find(".ui-datepicker-group-first").should_not have_link(/^(2)$/)
```

and that fixed the problem.